Exercise in "Grid Homology for Knots and Links"
I am reading the book "Grid Homology for Knots and Links" and came across the following exercise (2.1.15; a):

Consider the homology Element $[K_2] \in H_1(\mathbb{S}^3 \backslash K_1 ; \mathbb{Z}) \cong \mathbb{Z}$ given by $K_2 \subset \mathbb{S}^3 \backslash K_1$. If $\mu_1$ is the homology class of an oriented normal circle of $K_1$, then show that $[K_2] = lk(K_1, K_2) \cdot \mu_1$

Here $K_{1,2}$ are knots in the 3-sphere and $lk( \cdot , \cdot)$ is the linking number of two knots.
I have some basic questions about this exercise:

What exactly is $\mu_1$? Is it a generator of the group $H_1(\mathbb{S}^3 \backslash K_1 ; \mathbb{Z})$? And how can I visualize $\mu_1$, is it suitable to view it as any circle in $\mathbb{S}^3 \backslash K_1$?

More generally I am not so sure how to get some visual intuition for the group $H_1(\mathbb{S}^3 \backslash K_1 ; \mathbb{Z})$. I know that it is isomorphic to the infinite cyclic group by Mayer-Vietoris, but how do I for example see whether two elements are homologous?



There are a handful of questions about linking numbers and homology already, and it might be worth poking around to find them. Quick answer: "oriented normal circle" seems to mean "meridian", and your questions are answered on page 14.
